# Spring mvc template missing from STS 3.5.1

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I downloaded STS 3.5.1 and when I go **File** >> **New** >> **Spring Project** I could only see "Simple Java", "Simple Spring Maven" and "Simple Spring Web Maven".

see images on this url https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-iPROr9ozpRw/U7dzLG6CQrI/AAAAAAAAAN0/KGWXbml_OgI/w346-h500/sts+template.PNG

I have clicked refresh button.

**Updated**

when i see logs in **Error Log**, there is a error like this

> eclipse.buildId=3.5.1.201405030657-RELEASE-e43 java.version=1.7.0_09
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.springsource.sts.ide Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32
>   -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide
>
> Warning Sat Jul 05 10:56:44 ICT 2014 Connection to
>   https://raw.github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-gemfire-sts-templates/master/builds/descriptor.xml
>   failed on Connection reset. Retry attempt 0 started
>
> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset    at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:312)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:350)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1328)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
>     at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.doFlush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:271)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.flush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:276)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.flush(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:194)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:258)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:647)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1074)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.openStreams(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:621)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:879)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:570)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest(MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:106)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.sendRetrieveRequest(FileReader.java:422)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.read(FileReader.java:273)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.stream(RepositoryTransport.java:172)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor88.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.internal.core.net.P2TransportService.stream(P2TransportService.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.core.HttpUtil.stream(HttpUtil.java:165)
>     at
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.content.core.ContentManager.readFromUrl(ContentManager.java:326)
>     at
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.content.core.ContentManager.refresh(ContentManager.java:387)
>     at
>   org.springframework.ide.eclipse.wizard.template.DownloadDescriptorJob.run(DownloadDescriptorJob.java:42)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)

this is strange, because i can access that url using eclipse browse.

Help on this is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I can access the URL using a browser as well and it works inside of STS, too. Are you behind a firewall or proxy server maybe? And in that case, it is configured in Eclipse/STS network preferences correctly? You could also try to run Eclipse/STS using a more recent version of the JDK (1.7.0_09 seems to be outdated, maybe try 1.7.0_60).